# What exactly is the default NotificationCenter property?

Tags: ios, swift, notificationcenter

I want to create an additional `NotificationCenter` instance to separate my internal notifications from system notifications. However, when I looked at the class implementation, I did not understand what I was looking at.

```
open class NotificationCenter : NSObject {
    open class var default: NotificationCenter { get }
}
```

Where is the getter? What does `default` exactly get? This is what I was expecting to see:

```
extension NotificationCenter {
    static let default = NotificationCenter()
}
```

Is the `default` property a `static` singleton that we just don't see and the getter is just returning it?

And to implement my own custom center, could I just declare it the following way?

```
extension NotificationCenter {
    static let custom = NotificationCenter()
}
```

Comment: Yes, `NotificationCenter.default` is a singleton.  You can create your own notification centre instances exactly as you have shown.

Comment: The first block of code in your question is simply the available interface. It is not in any way meant to show the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NotificationCenter.default` gets the default `NotificationCenter` instance for your app, which is a singleton.

The iOS frameworks are not open source, so when you look at the definition of `NotificationCenter.default` you see the interface it exposes, not the implementation, which would probably look very much like the code you expected to see.

You can, indeed, create your own `NotificationCenter` instances using `NotificationCenter()`